# Simple dropdown filter in React? React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a  filter in React which filters regions of the world from an api. However I didn't realise you can't style  .

I would like to make a basic dropdown that I can style myself.

Heres my Filter:

```
const Filters = ({ region, handleSearch, handleSelect }) => {
  return (
    <div className='filter-wrapper'>

      <select className='filter-select' value={region} onChange={handleSelect}>
        <option value=''>Search by Region</option>
        <option value='Europe'>Europe</option>
        <option value='Asia'>Asia</option>
        <option value='Africa'>Africa</option>
        <option value='Americas'>Americas</option>
        <option value='Oceania'>Oceania</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Filters;
```

State is managed in a Homepage:

```
  const [region, setRegion] = useState('');

  const handleSelect = (event) => {
    setRegion(event.target.value);
  };

      <Filters
        region={region}
        handleSelect={handleSelect}
      />
```

To clarify I don't need the css.
I would like to change this  to something that allows me to use css. I want the same functionality but a dropdown that I can use in a real production app for example.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I would like to change this <select> to something that allows me to use css. I want the same functionality but a dropdown that I can use in a real production app for example.

Comment: React already allows styling, via in-line `style` prop, or by using a `className` prop associated with a style sheet. There are further options that allow you to create "styled react component" with the CSS bakes right in or set via a theme object. What are you looking for? Can you narrow down your search area? Or are you just asking how to style elements in React in general?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely style the `<select>` and its `<options>` yourself [if you want](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp).  It's probably easier to use a package like [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) but a fully featured library of React UI components (like [antd](https://ant.design/)) may work better.  Sure, you can reinvent the wheel, but unless you want to update your raw css, including responsive designs for mobile on all browsers, best to let the tried and true options do the heavy lifting.  You can always customize them as well.

Comment: Sorry what I meant was I can style the select like you suggest. But cannot style the <option> tags.